# Determine $x\in X=\{1,...,n\}$ by halving $X$ in $k$ ways s.t. each two halvings share $n/4$ elements.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $X=\{1,...,n=2^k\}$ and $H_1,...,H_k$ be $\frac{n}{2}$-element subsets of $X$ which satisfy $|H_i\cap H_j|=\frac{n}{4}$ for each $i\neq j$.

My question is: can we determine the $x\in X$ uniquely by knowing whether $x\in H_i$ for each $i$?

Or equivalently, $|H_1\cap H_2\cap ... \cap H_k|=1$ ? (If this holds then $|\overline{H_1}\cap H_2\cap ... \cap H_k|$ etc. is also 1 by symmetry. So for example if we know $x\in H_i$ for all $i\neq1$ we can determine $x$ as the unique element of $\overline{H_1}\cap H_2\cap ... \cap H_k$.)

By definition $|H_1|=\frac{n}{2}$ and $|H_1\cap H_2|=\frac{n}{4}$, so
I think intuitively that adding one more $H_i$ to this intersection halves the number of the elements in the intersection, thus $|H_1\cap H_2\cap ... \cap H_k|=\frac{n}{2^k}=1$.
But the definition say nothing about intersections of 3 or more $H_i$'s...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $k=3, H_1=\{1, 2, 3, 4 \}, H_2=\{1, 2, 5, 6 \}, H_3=\{1, 2, 7, 8\}.$